# What do these values mean in a magnetic field meter?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

This is not a real-life field meter. The below image with 4 values in the field meter is from a simulation. I wanted to know what these values mean, especially the first 2.
Can you please help me?

Thanks for your time

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that they are the magnitude and $x$ and $y$ components of the ${\bf B}$  field measured in gauss. If the device is to measure the Earths magnetc field (which is a few gauss) the  $\theta$ is probably the [dip angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dip). The $x$ axis would thebe oriented to true  north.

Comment: It looks like the first is the absolute value of the B field, the next two are the x and y components respectively and the final one is the angle relative to the x axis?

Comment: so the 'Bx' is the magnitude of the magnetic field on the x-axis and the 'By' is the magnitude of the magnetic field on the y axis?. Also, this simulation is the measure the magnetic field of electromagnets and bar magnets.

Comment: @CoolBean $B_x$ and $B_y$ are the $x$ and $y$ components of the magnetic field at that point, i.e. if you resolve your vectors into components along $x$ and $y$ axis, these would be those components. On vector addition, they would result in the same vector.

Answer (score 0):

The meter seems to show the magnetic field intensity at the point of interest. The magnetic field intensity, in this case, has been measured in units of gauss ($1 G = 10^{-4} T$). The angle $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis and the magnetic field. $B_x$ and $B_y$ are the $x$ and $y$ components of the magnetic field. Since the angle $\theta$ is zero, the $x$-component $B_x = B \cos\theta = B$ and the $y$-component $B_y = B \sin\theta = 0$